# getting dropdown data from database using ajax and java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets

how to retrieve data of multiple dropdowns from database using ajax and java servlet. plz can anyone help.

I have total 6 dropdowns which should be populated one after the another based on previous selection and when last dropdown is selected then choose file input box should be displayed. All these data of dropdown should be retrieved from database using ajax and  java servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array having 6 objects and each of them filled with all possible values for each dropdown and then iterating them and displaying in the frontend, simple isn't it?